# has no exported member of typescript class in fullstack application

Tags: angular, typescript

[this is my folder second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhC2l.png)[This is my folderstrcture of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkdMs.png)

> I create a fullstack application i create some classes and imported it
>   i ntomy typescript class but it show me an error  has no exported
>   member 'UserEntity'.
>
> ERROR in src/app/service/http-client.service.ts:3:28 - error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module '../../model/UserEntity'.
>
> ```
> 3 import { UserEntity } from '../../model/UserEntity';
> ```
>
> src/app/admin/user/user.component.ts:2:10 - error TS2305: Module
>   '"../../model/UserEntity"' has no exported member 'UserEntity'.
>
> ```
> 2 import { UserEntity } from '../../model/UserEntity';
> ```
>
> UserEntity.ts

```
export class UserEntity {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        type: string;  
        password: string;
      }
```

> user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserEntity } from '../../model/UserEntity';
import { HttpClientService } from '../../service/http-client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Array<UserEntity>;
  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpClientService.getUsers().subscribe(
              response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response),
            );

  }
  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
        this.user = response;
      }

}
```

> http-client-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserEntity } from '../../model/UserEntity';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }
  getUsers()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<UserEntity[]>('http://localhost:8080/user/get');
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your folder structure?

Comment: see my folder strcture.Iadd a link above my question

Comment: Make sure the file `../../model/UserEntity.ts` exists (and it's case sensitive)

Comment: this folder structure not showing userEntity.ts

Comment: look my folder strcture I added it

Comment: It should be `../model/UserEntity` in the HTTP service.

Comment: were u able to solve this ?